# scikit-learn: Nearest Neighbors

Tags: scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I'm looking at sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors and the corresponding BallTree class. My question is if there is any way to continue training / append new data to the tree? Or does it always have to be completely refitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Nearest Neighbors is an algorithm that checks for proximity of a given data to a cluster of data pertaining to different classes, yes, it would require refitting. There are no learned parameters (like `weights` in neural networks) in Nearest Neighbors, just the value of distances (e.g. Manhattan, Euclidean)

Comment: ok. thought so but always good to be sure. if you have experience with the sklearn implementation, is it possible to get the k nearest neighbors of entry in the tree by providing it's index? This would avoid having to query for it and then setting n+1 because I would not want the self-hit.